# Does dimensions of GIF affect performance of web page?

Tags: javascript, html

Ignoring the size of each GIF, here are 2 ways in which I am trying to load GIFs

1. Load the GIF's by stretching/compresssing to default size of 400px x 400px
2. Load the same GIFs by tweaking the default size to 100px x 100px

Will these two cases affect the performance due to rendering, if so how much performance gain can we expect by decreasing the size of the images?

Note: These are the dimensions of the elements and I am not tweaking the actual size of the GIFs

Comment: Changing rendering resolution is always going to affect performance, because it changes the number of pixels that have to be written to, as well as any scaling performed on the source image (and the expense of that scaling depends on the algorithm in use). The amount that the size impacts the performance will depend to a large degree on the browser and system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resizing images on the browser **does** affect performance when it comes to rendering.

From [tips for best performance](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#no_scale),

> Don't use a bigger image than you need just because you can set the
>   width and height in HTML. If you need    then your image (mycat.jpg) should be
>   100x100px rather than a scaled down 500x500px image.

About how much it affects, it depends on how much resize you apply, and how many images you resize on one page.

Ah, [found the link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/10/pinterest-paint-performance-case-study/) I was trying to remember :

> Long image decoding, unnecessary image resizing, heavy animation and
>   data processing can all lead to dropped frames, which reduces the
>   frame rate, resulting in janky pages

Comment: Does this mean scaling down a 500px x 500px image down to 50px x 50px is a bad idea as well?

Comment: @SrikanthRayabhagi : Image resizing on the browser, whether scaling up or down, will cost more than serving the image without scaling.

Comment: @SrikanthRayabhagi : Have I understood your question properly? You're asking about resizing the `gif` on the client using HTML, right?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about resizing image using HTML and right now I was under the impression that scaling up might be costlier due to increased rendering as @ChrisHayes mentioned but it is new thing to learn as scaling down is costlier as well. Thanks for the answer.